# Content-Type header [] is not supported when trying to load csv into es

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I'am trying to load and index csv file into elasticsearch.

I'm trying to use this post: 
[Index CSV to ElasticSearch in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41573616/index-csv-to-elasticsearch-in-python)

The csv file has the following 3 fields:

```
text,existence,existence.confidence
```

My code looks:

```
from elasticsearch import helpers, Elasticsearch
import csv

es = Elasticsearch()
with open('test.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    helpers.bulk(es, reader, index='test-index', doc_type='test-type')
```

but I'm getting the following error:

```
raise HTTP_EXCEPTIONS.get(status_code, TransportError)(status_code, error_message, additional_info)
elasticsearch.exceptions.TransportError: TransportError(406, 'Content-Type header [] is not supported')
```

Python: 3.7
ES: 6.8

What is wrong and how can I fix it ?

Comment: Please add the version of elasticsearch-py as well, as it looks related to this issue: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-py/issues/445

Comment: A workaround to the above issue is to use a custom connection class and have that class always set the content type header to json